# Как присоединить БД из 32bit в 64bit

Tags: windows, sql-server, база-данных

Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить такую проблему. Пытаюсь присоединить БД в MS SQL 2005 (файл mdf), но получаю ошибку 5120 (отказано в доступе). Изюминка в том, что у меня стоит 64-битная Windows 7 Home Basic, я думаю дело в этом, а mdf наверно создавался для 32bit. Как можно решить такую проблему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще никак не связано.
Если отказано в доступе - проверяйте, есть ли у учетки, под которой запущен MS SQL, права на папку и файл базы данных. Присоединить только один mdf файл не получится - должен быть как минимум еще файл ldf - файл лога.

Answer (score 1):

Да, вы правы, причина была в другом: надо было открыть Managment Studio от имени администратора.